# Using a null IDisposable value with the using statement

Tags: c#, null, idisposable, using-statement

The following code produces no errors when executed:

```
using ((IDisposable)null) {
    Console.WriteLine("A");
}
Console.WriteLine("B");
```

**Is a *null* value to `using` 'allowed'?** If so, where is it documented?

Most C# code I've seen will create a "dummy/NOP" IDisposable object - is there a particular need for a non-null Disposable object? Was there ever?

If/since null is allowed, it allows placing a null guard *inside* the using statement as opposed to before or around.

The [C# Reference on Using](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement) does not mention null values.

Comment: The article you've mentioned links to specification (which is the source of truth - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/statements#the-using-statement) as well shows how it is expanded - `if (font1 != null)
      ((IDisposable)font1).Dispose();` with definitive check for null result... So is your actual question about "is there a particular need for a non-null Disposable [dummy] object"?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Which by answering the other question is "technically no" - I suppose a dummy instance could still be useful when the object had other properties that may be accessed without wanting to burden the caller. I don't know why I completely glazed over that example.. thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes, a null value is allowed. §8.13, "The using statement", of the C# 5.0 specification says:

> If a `null` resource is acquired, then no call to `Dispose` is made, and no exception is thrown.

The specification then provides the following expansion for a `using` statement of the form

```
using (ResourceType resource = expression) statement
```

when `resource` is a reference type (other than `dynamic`):

```
{
    ResourceType resource = expression;
    try {
        statement;
    }
    finally {
        if (resource != null) ((IDisposable)resource).Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: Link to the specification can be found from article mentioned in the question - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/statements#the-using-statement